# angularjs pull out multiple values from select

Tags: angularjs

I am a pretty new to Angularjs and am having an issue on my select

I have populated my select fields but when I want to show what has been selected from the json I can only pull out the one value.  I need both the name and the type but in 2 different places in my webpage

Fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/ktcle/9Ymvt/1455/

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-options="style.name as style.name for style in styles" ng-model="style">
     <option style="display:none" value="">select a style</option>
  </select>

  <h2>selected: {{style}}</h2>

  <h3>type: {{styles.type}}</h3>

</div>
```

and

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.styles = [
    {
    name: "Red",
    code: "123",
    type: "t-shirt"
    },
{
    name: "Yellow",
    code: "456",
    type: "vest"
    },
{
    name: "Green",
    code: "789",
    type: "jumper"
    },
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify the entire `style` object as the value in your `ng-options` expression.  And, bind `ng-model` to something defined outside of `ng-options`.

```
<select ng-options="style as style.name for style in styles" ng-model="selected.style">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/1456/

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Rewrite your ng-options as `"style.name for style in styles"`. The way you have it will display style.name and select style.name. You want to select style in stead
2. For type your styles variable is mistakenly pluralized. Should be: `<h3>type: {{style.type}}</h3>`

```html
<div ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
  <select ng-options="style.name for style in styles" ng-model="style">
     <option style="display:none" value="">select a style</option>
  </select>

  <h2>selected: {{style}}</h2>

  <h3>type: {{style.type}}</h3>

</div>
```

Here's your updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnibecker/B2wJ4/

Comment: another big thank you, sorry I can only accept one as accepted answer